# Identificar una tercia en un numero decimal

Tags: c#

Como puedo identificar una tercia de un número decimal con 5 dígitos después del punto.
en c#.
Ej.
Si tenemos:

0.15171 = si es tercia De (1)

0.17902 = no es tercia.

0.79277 = si es tercia.De(7)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Saludos Luis, bienvenido a SOes, por curiosidad ¿Qué has intentado?

Comment: Si es en C#, por que añades java como tag?

Comment: No es necesario que sea en c#.

Comment: puedes definir que es `tercia`, con los ejemplos no me es claro

Comment: Si aparecen 3 números iguales.

Comment: Ya agregue una imagen,le he hecho primero con un par

Comment: creo que ya lo tengo

Comment: en el código primero lo hice con un array de enteros para mas facilidad,

Comment: Si lo has conseguido puedes añadir tu propia respuesta. De todas maneras, nunca pegues código como una imagen, es preferible que copies el texto y lo pegues. Aunque supongo que esto es un trabajo de escuela, te voy a añadir una respuesta sobre como hacerlo usando LINQ.

Comment: Gracias, buen punto

Answer (score 1):

Convierte el numero a string y crea alguna función que cuente cuantas veces aparece cada carácter, si esa función retorna 3 tendrías la tercia que buscas

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Aunque imagino que es un trabajo escolar en el que el objetivo es practicar bucles etc.., voy a añadir una posible respuesta ya que me parece interesante para demostrar la simplicidad que nos da LINQ para tareas de este tipo. Este ejemplo funciona para cualquier número de dígitos,no solo para 5:

```
decimal numero = 0.7927979M;

//Obtenemos el separador decimal del sistema para poder separar la parte decimal
char decimalSeparator = Convert.ToChar(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator);
string parteDecimal = numero.ToString().Split(decimalSeparator)[1]; //obtenemos la parte decimal
var tercias = parteDecimal.Select(x => int.Parse(x.ToString())) //separamos cada uno de los digitos 
                          .GroupBy(x => x)                      //agrupamos por digito
                          .Where(x=>x.Count()==3);              //y nos quedamos con los que sean 3

foreach (var tercia in tercias)
{
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("El número {0} es tercia de {1}", numero, tercia.Key));
}

//Salida por consola con este ejemplo:
//El número 0,7927979 es tercia de 7
//El número 0,7927979 es tercia de 9
```